# Following sibling within an xpath is not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, lxml

I've been trying to scoop out a portion of text out of some html elements using xapth but It seems I'm going somewhere wrong that is why I can't make it.

Html elements:

```
htmlelem = """
<div class="content">
    <p>Type of cuisine: </p>International
</div>
"""
```

I would like to dig out `International` using xpath. I know I could get success using `.next_sibling` If I wanted to extract the same using `css selector` but I'm not interested in going that route.

That said If I try like this I can get the same using `xpath`:

```
tree.xpath("//*[@class='content']/p/following::text()")[0]
```

But the above expression is not what I'm after cause I can't use the same within selenium webdriver If I stick to `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

The only way that I'm interested in is like the following but it is not working:

```
"//*[@class='content']/p/following::*"
```

Real-life example:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

htmlelem = """
<div class="content">
    <p>Type of cuisine: </p>International
</div>
"""
tree = fromstring(htmlelem)
item = tree.xpath("//*[@class='content']/p/following::text()")[0].strip()
elem = tree.xpath("//*[@class='content']/p/following::*")[0].text
print(elem)
```

In the above example, I can get success printing `item` but can't printing `elem`. However, I would like to modify the expression used within `elem`.

***How can I make it work so that the same `xpath` I can use within `lxml` library or within `selenium`?***

Comment: Your expression works @Daniel Haley and so does mine `"//*[@class='content']/p/following::text()"` but the thing is I need to call the ***`.text`*** outside of xpath like the way I tried within `elem`. Thanks.

Comment: With the current implementation of selenium it's not possible thought you get an xpath that return the text node. Check [here](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/340) for more details.

Comment: you have to relay on `execute_script` to get the specific text node. with `//div/text()[2]` xpath in the js.

Comment: Note, in all of these examples, you really want to be using the `following-sibling` axis in preference to the `following` axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP was looking for a solution which extracts the text from outside the xpath, the following should do that, albeit in a somewhat awkward manner:

```
tree.xpath("//*[@class='content']")[0][0].tail
```

Output:

> International

The need for this approach is a result of the way lxml parses the html code:
`tree.xpath("//*[@class='content']")` results in a `list` of length=1.
The first (and only) element in the list - `tree.xpath("//*[@class='content']")[0]` is a `lxml.html.HtmlElement` which itself can be treated as a list and also has length=1.

In the `tail` of the first (and only) element in that `lxml.html.HtmlElement` hides the desired output...

Comment: Thanks Jack for your time to write an answer. Would you please clarify in comment why there are two indices `[0][0]` just before `.tail`. This approach is quite new to me. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU - I edited the answer to (hopefully) clarify it.